# iPhone application for TOTP that uses Secure Enclave to store secrets?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, keychain

Is there an iPhone application for [TOTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-based_One-time_Password_Algorithm) that uses the [Secure Enclave](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/certificate_key_and_trust_services/keys/storing_keys_in_the_secure_enclave) to store the keys?

Some popular TOTP applications for iPhone are FreeOTP, Authy and Google Authenticator, but it is not clear if any of them stores the secret keys in the Secure Enclave.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 1Password with a local vault. 1Password protects its data decryption secret with a private key stored only in the Secure Enclave, which in turn protects the TOTP shared secrets.